# Warning: @OA\Items() parent type must be "array" , how to fix it?

Tags: php, swagger

I am facing this error but can't figure how to fix it.
I am coding the API documentation from my PHP app, using zircote/swagger-php library and for some reason, some are presenting a weird error like shown below.

The most odd is that I have a bunch of files and some present, others don't.

Let's see come code:

```
<?php 

use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**
 * @OA\Schema(
 *      schema="CreateIncidentsRequests",
 *      title="Create Incidents Request",
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="object",
 *          type="string",
 *          example="incidents"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="action",
 *          type="string",
 *          example="create"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="data",
 *          type="object",
 *              @OA\Items(
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="organization",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="1"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="site",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="1"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="name",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="Test Title"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="affiliate",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="1"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="description",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="Description body"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="reported_by",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="User Name"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="discovered",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="2022-10-03"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="type",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="1"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="affected",
 *                      type="boolean",
 *                      example="true"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="active",
 *                      type="boolean",
 *                      example="true"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="reason",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example=""
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="regulatory_act",
 *                      type="string",
 *                      example="HIPAA"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="investigating",
 *                      type="boolean",
 *                      example="true"
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="tasks",
 *                      type="object",
 *                      @OA\Items()
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="files",
 *                      type="object",
 *                      @OA\Items()
 *                  ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                      property="notes",
 *                      type="object",
 *                      @OA\Items()
 *                  ),
 *              ),
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="organization",
 *          type="string",
 *          example="1"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="site",
 *          oneOf={
 *              @OA\Schema(type="string"),
 *              @OA\Schema(type="boolean"),
 *          },
 *          example="1 | false"
 *      )
 * )
 */
class CreateIncidentsRequest
{

}
```

The error is:

`Warning: @OA\Items() parent type must be "array" in /Users/marcellopato/Documents/Sites/compliancy.com/guard_includes/Requests/Incidents/create.inc on line 5`

There are a bunch of other files and some presents the error, and some, don't. Make no sense.
Any ideas?
I'm lost here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `data` property supposed to be an object or an array of objects?

Comment: I've changed that to array, but the problem stills. And the error seems to be at line 5 witches is in the very beginning of the code… I start to thinking this is just a minor bug

Comment: HI @OlegOlegovich, how are you? Can't remember if I did, I'm sorry...

Comment: @MarcelloPato sure, no problem. I've added also an answer how I fixed it and it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are need to change `type="object"` to `type="array"` for your `data` property